# pandas group by ID

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following data frame and my goal is to fill the last columns as follows

- Time to x = default to whatever time (in hours) appears in column x
- Time to y = the difference between column y and x group by ID
- Time to z = the difference between column z and y group by ID

[image]

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Note: ID can have different input and that Time to should be assigned to value match.
Meaning Time to y will be same row where y is not null.

I'm new in pandas, help needed
Expected output:
[image]

Comment: It would be useful if you showed your expected output in the table.

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

See the code below. It is not clear what you mean by `x group by ID` nor by `y group by ID` so I have taken a guess (max value used) so as to produce your expected output. I have used temporary columns _y and _z so you can inspect these if required. Note that according to your rules there is a mistake in your expected output for `time_to_z` (which should be 9-5=4).

The code uses `np.where` which tests a condition and sets different values for **True** and **False**.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': [1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 9, 10],
                   'x' : [None, 3, None, None,None, 1, 1, None,None,None,None, 2,None,None, 1],
                   'y' : [5, None, 8, 9,None,None,None, 5,None,None, 2,None, 3,None,None],
                   'z' : [None, None, None, None, 3,None,None,None, 9, 4,None,None,None,6,None]
                   })

df['time_to_x'] = df['x']

df['_y'] = df.groupby('ID')['x'].transform(max)
df['time_to_y'] = np.where(np.isnan(df['_y']), df['y'], df['y'] - df['_y'])

df['_z'] = df.groupby('ID')['y'].transform(max)
df['time_to_z'] = np.where(np.isnan(df['_z']), df['z'], df['z'] - df['_z'])

df = df.drop(['_y', '_z'], axis = 1)

print(df)
```

giving

```
    ID    x    y    z  time_to_x  time_to_y  time_to_z
0    1  NaN  5.0  NaN        NaN        5.0        NaN
1    2  3.0  NaN  NaN        3.0        NaN        NaN
2    2  NaN  8.0  NaN        NaN        5.0        NaN
3    3  NaN  9.0  NaN        NaN        9.0        NaN
4    3  NaN  NaN  3.0        NaN        NaN       -6.0
5    4  1.0  NaN  NaN        1.0        NaN        NaN
6    5  1.0  NaN  NaN        1.0        NaN        NaN
7    5  NaN  5.0  NaN        NaN        4.0        NaN
8    5  NaN  NaN  9.0        NaN        NaN        4.0
9    6  NaN  NaN  4.0        NaN        NaN        4.0
10   7  NaN  2.0  NaN        NaN        2.0        NaN
11   8  2.0  NaN  NaN        2.0        NaN        NaN
12   9  NaN  3.0  NaN        NaN        3.0        NaN
13   9  NaN  NaN  6.0        NaN        NaN        3.0
14  10  1.0  NaN  NaN        1.0        NaN        NaN
```